# In CQRS/Eventsourcing which is best approach for a parent to modify the state of all it's children ??

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

**Usecase:** Suppose I have the following aggregates

- **Root aggregate** - CustomerRootAggregate (manages each CustomerAggregate)
- **Child aggregate of the Root aggregate** - CustomerAggregate (there are 10 customers)

**Question:** How do I send `DisableCustomer` command to all the 10 CustomerAggregate to update their state to be disabled ?

```
customerState.enabled = false
```

**Solutions:** Since CQRS does not allow the write side to query the read side to get a list of CustomerAggregate IDs I thought of the following:

1. `CustomerRootAggregate` always store the IDs of all it's `CustomerAggregate` in the database as json. When a Command for `DisableAllCustomers` is received by `CustomerRootAggregate` it will fetch the CustomerIds json and send `DisableCustomer` command to all the children where each child will restore it's state before applying `DisableCustomer` command. But this means I will have to maintain CustomerIds json record's consistency.
2. The Client (Browser - UI) should always send the list of CustomerIds to apply `DisableCustomer` to. But this will be problematic for a database with thousands of customers.
3. In the REST API Layer check for the command `DisableAllCustomers` and fetch all the IDs from the read side and sends DisableAllCustomers(ids) with IDs populated to write side.

Which is a recommended approach or is a better approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **Root aggregate** - CustomerRootAggregate (manages each CustomerAggregate)
> - **Child aggregate of the Root aggregate** - CustomerAggregate (there are 10 customers)

For starters, the language "child aggregate" is a bit confusing.  Your model includes a "parent" entity that holds a direct reference to a "child" entity, then both of those entities must be part of the same aggregate.

However, you might have a Customer aggregate for each customer, and a CustomerSet aggregate that manages a collection of Id.

> How do I send DisableCustomer command to all the 10 CustomerAggregate to update their state to be disabled ?

The usual answer is that you run a query to get the set of Customers to be disabled, and then you dispatch a disableCustomer command to each.

So both 3 and 2 are reasonable answers, with the caveat that you need to consider what your requirements are if some of the DisableCustomer commands fail.

2 in particular is seductive, because it clearly articulates that the client (human operator) is describing a task,  which the application then translates into commands to by run by the domain model.

Trying to pack "thousands" of customer ids into the message may be a concern, but for several use cases you can find a way to shrink that down.  For instance, if the task is "disable all", then client can send to the application instructions for how to recreate the "all" collection -- ie: "run this query against this specific version of the collection" describes the list of customers to be disabled unambiguously.

> When a Command for DisableAllCustomers is received by CustomerRootAggregate it will fetch the CustomerIds json and send DisableCustomer command to all the children where each child will restore it's state before applying DisableCustomer command. But this means I will have to maintain CustomerIds json record's consistency.

This is close to a right idea, but not quite there.  You dispatch a command to the collection aggregate.  If it accepts the command, it produces an event that describes the customer ids to be disabled.  This domain event is persisted as part of the event stream of the collection aggregate.

Subscribe to these events with an event handler that is responsible for creating a *process manager*.  This process manager is another event sourced state machine.  It looks sort of like an aggregate, but it responds to events.  When an event is passed to it, it updates its own state, saves those events off in the current transaction, and then schedules commands to each Customer aggregate.

But it's a bunch of extra work to do it that way.  Conventional wisdom suggests that you should usually begin by assuming that the process manager approach isn't necessary, and only introduce it if the business demands it.  "Premature automation is the root of all evil" or something like that.